# GNUPlot data block titles

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I have a csv file which I am trying to plot with GNUPlot. At the moment I don't know what the rules are for column headers.

Here is an example:

```
t,r,y
0,0,0
0.1,... values
... more values


t,r,y
0,0,0
0.1,... values
... more values


... more data blocks
```

But I cannot plot this with gnuplot - I receive the error: `bad data on line 1 of file timeseries.csv`

My guess is that gnuplot doesn't like the title for the datablock?

I think that perhaps it requires a `#` sign before to signify that this is a comment, or perhaps it requires the title to be in a string format such as: `"t,r,y"`

(These are just 2 suggestions I found while googling.)

If I want to pass information about the data block as a title, what are the rules?

- How many title lines (comment lines) am I allowed?
- How do I format a comment line?
- Do I have to have a comment title for each column of my data, separated by `,` commas?
- Can I have more / less text data separated by `,` as the number of columns?

Edit: As an example, say I want to send the output filename (for generating png images for example) with each data block.

Can I do something like: `#file1.csv` at the start of my block and get gnuplot to create a png file with this name? The next block would then be `#file2.csv`, etc. Or perhaps I would send the axis labels and graph title in this manner, for example.

Comment: From the gnuplot documentation:   `index ’<name>’ selects the data set with name ’<name>’. Names are assigned to data sets in comment
lines. The comment character and leading white space are removed from the comment line. If the
resulting line starts with <name>, the following data set is now named <name> and can be selected.
Example:
plot ’file’ index ’Population’
Please note that every comment that starts with <name> will name the following data set. To avoid
problems it may be useful to choose a naming scheme like ’== Population ==’ or ’[Population]’.
`

Answer (score 0):

GNUplot does not parse labels. If you want to have labels in your data files, you must put a hashmark (#) at the beginning of the line, to signify it as a comment.

Axis labels, titles and so on can be set with the `set` command. Here's an example showing (e.g.) the changing temperature of some test tubes:

```
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Temperature"
set title "Some interesting experiments"
plot "timeseries.csv" using 1:3 title "tube 15" with lines, \
     "timeseries.csv" using 2:3 title "tube 23" with lines
```

**EDIT**: I assumed that the question was aimed at extracting labels from the data file. If not, please specify a minimal data set and what you want GNUplot to generate.